# Effect of change in Viewpoint->{x,y,z} on the size of graphic objects is not what I expected. How to fix?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If you run the following code snippet:

```
 Manipulate[
   Graphics3D[
     {Cuboid[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}], Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 1]}, 
      ViewPoint -> {1, 1, a}, AxesOrigin -> {0,0,0}
   ], 
   {a, 1, 100}
 ]
```

and move the viewpoint from (1,1,1) to (1,1,100) with the slider you will see that after a while the objects remain fixed in size.

#### Questions.

#### 1. When I move the viewpoint further away from the scene I want the objects to become smaller. How should this be done in Mathematica?

( EDIT: )

#### 2. What is the position of the 'camera' in relation to Viewpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [ViewAngle](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewAngle.html). Under "More Information", note that the default setting `ViewAngle -> Automatic` is effectively equivalent to `ViewAngle -> All` when you zoom far enough out.

You just need to add an explicit setting for ViewAngle:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}], Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 1]},
   ViewPoint -> {1, 1, a}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  ViewAngle -> 35 Degree], {a, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to study all the Viewpoint related properties first. I don't think I get it yet, although the behavior of Graphics3D has become somewhat clearer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the camera viewpoint really coincides with the position given by `ViewPoint`. Because Mathematica scales the result to fit in about the same image you don't see much changes but they are there. The perspective changes considerably. Try, for instance, to move away from a semi-transparant square and you'll see that the farther you go, the more the projection becomes an orthogonal projection:

[image]

If you want to scale your image according to distance you can use `ImageSize`. `SphericalRegion` is good to stabilize the image.

```
Manipulate[
 vp = {1, 1, a};
 Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}], Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 1]},
  ViewPoint -> vp,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  ImageSize -> 500/Norm[vp]],
 {a, 1, 100}
 ]
```

[image]

[animation made with some `ImagePadding` to keep object in the center. I stopped the animation at *a* = 10, the image gets pretty small after that]

Comment: @Sjoerd, Then how can I 'walk through' a scene of objects? Or fly through a virtual solar system ( I remember I have seen that one in Mathematica once ) ?

Comment: @ndroock1 It seems you should now have the tools to do just that. You might need ViewCenter and ViewVertical too.

Comment: @ndroock1 what is wrong with Manipulate[vp = {1, 1, a};
 Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}], Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 1]},ViewPoint -> vp, ViewAngle \[Rule] Pi/4, PlotRange \[Rule] {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, SphericalRegion -> True], {a, 1, 10}]

Comment: @ndroock1 I think Andrew's ViewPoint approach is the way to go if you go beyond the simple scene of your question.

Comment: @Sjoerd, As I commented on Andrew's answer I need to study the ViewPoint related properties and probably more. It seems I don't quite understand the Graphics3D command yet.